# Getting java.sql.RowId from Java ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, rowid

This is proving to be more difficult than I expected. I am trying to get the Oracle rowid (`java.sql.RowId`) for a row from a `ResultSet` object.

```
RowId rowid = rs.getRowId("rowid");
```

this fails, doesn't like the input String "rowid".

```
Integer columnIndex = 2;
RowId rowid = rs.getRowId(columnIndex);
```

this fails because it doesn't like the integer value of the column index.

**So which column index do I pass for a metacolumn such as rownum or rowid?**

If I were the designers, I would have made rowid have a columnindex of 0, -1, or -2, or -3, or something, but that's me.

Comment: `rowid` has to be part of your query. Column indices start with 1 not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to select the rowid as a column in your query, then access the column (by name or index) with the getRowId() method.

For example.

```
    select
        rowid,
        blammy
    from
        tablename
    where
        something = desiredvalue
```

Then

```
    RowId rowid = rs.getRowId("rowid");
```

or

```
    RowId rowid = rs.getRowId(1);
```